# I can't rewrite all my jQuery website in AngularJS while I really need two way data-binding

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, angularjs, backbone.js

I have heavy use of jQuery (many jQuery and jQuery UI plugins) in a website I am building. I was rendering templates server side till I stumbeled upon this amazing [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31366386/frontend-vs-backend-template-rendering/) that advices returning only JSON from server.

So I rebuilt all the stuff in backend and now, I have a JSON API and I am planning to integrate a front-end framework to do templating in the browser with data binding.

I heard that BackboneJS has jQuery as dependency, so I think It is better to use it in my case (me who doesn't want to rewrite all the jQuery plugins). Personnaly, I liked AngularJS documentation so much but I feel that AngularJS+ jQuery is bad choice. Can someone please erase my confusion and confirm to me that BackboneJS fits with my situation? (JS files size matters as I think)

Your usual enlightments are highly invaluble to me in this moment.

Comment: I've been into AngularJS for about a month now and from what I've read in various places that mixing angularjs and jquery isn't a good practice. Although, after playing around with angularjs and bootstrap, I don't really see a reason to use jquery with angularjs...which makes me wonder if DOM manipulation is almost a thing of the past anymore.

Comment: Backbone is really verbose and on the decline, i wouldn't choose it. Angular on the other side is pretty mature, has no problem with jQuery, but a version 2 is expected (since some times now) so i'm not sure i would advice you to dive in it "right now" ... why not trying react ;-)

Comment: Backbone's only "required" dependancy is Underscore.

Answer (score 1):

backbone has a nice plugin for 2-way data bindings. https://nytimes.github.io/backbone.stickit/

And backbone.js allows you to use any other frameworks, cause backbone isn't framework as AngularJS.

Even, you can use backbone.js + AngularJS in one project, picking models or events from backbone

So, it's easier to use only that small plugins which fits your tasks instead of rewriting whole app with another framework